# Creating arrays for permutations within a subsection of a list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, permutation, heaps-algorithm

So I have a list:

```
a 25
b 18
c 18
d 18
e 14
f 14
g 12
... and so on
```

For each number that matches, I have to get every permutation of the identifier. The lists I would need from my example would be as follows:

```
abcdefg
abdcefg
acbdefg
acdbefg
adbcefg
adcbefg
abcdfeg
abdcfeg
acbdfeg
acdbfeg
adbcfeg
adcbfeg
```

Steps I am taking currently to solve the problem:

1. Read in the list, place each value in an array ([a][12]) and place that in an ArrayList
2. I then find if there are any repeating numbers and make note of it within a HashMap
3. I then have a for loop set up to go through the HashMap. If the number didn't repeat, I just add it to the list. If the number did repeat, I use Heap's algorithm to get every permutation.

If I were to work through it, I would be adding the numbers to a list like this:

```
a
abcd
abdc
adbc
...
abcdef
abcdfe
abdcef
adbcfe
...
abcdefg
abcdfeg
```

My current code doesn't work as intended (generates only one list) and I'm not even sure how to begin writing a code that would continuously generate new lists, while also appending the old lists. I apologize for being lost, I'm in a data structures course right now and it all feels out of my familiarity zone (we just started discussing linked lists).

Note 1: allLists holds all the current lists (a, abcd, adcb,) and permutationList holds all the permutations of the list.

Note 2: I'm doing this through a boolean list, but used letters as an easy visual representation for what I'm trying to accomplish

Code where I expect the problem to be:

```
public static Boolean[] combine (int i, int j) {
    int aLen = allLists.get(j).length;
    int bLen = permutationList.get(i).length;

    Boolean[] newList = new Boolean[aLen + bLen];
    System.arraycopy(allLists.get(j), 0, newList, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(permutationList.get(i), 0, newList, aLen, bLen);

    return newList;
}

public static void setAllLists() {
    if(allLists.size() == 0) {
        allLists.add(permutationList.get(0));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < permutationList.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < allLists.size(); j++) {
                Boolean[] newList = combine(i,j);
                if(i == 0) {
                    allLists.set(j, newList);
                }
                else {
                    allLists.add(newList);
            }
        }
    }
    permutationList.clear();
}
```

Comment: Are numbers in an increasing order ? Or they could be randomly placed ?

Comment: They're in decreasing order. The bottom numbers have more duplicates. I edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: Is `bcdaefg` a valid output or should the output string be in strictly increasing order?

Comment: `bcdaefg` is not a valid output. It has to be strictly in increasing order (highest number first) so [a][bcd][ef][g] are the various subsections of this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions:** 
I don't know your input format but I have assumed that I have two lists `alphabets` which have list of alphabets and `values` which have list of corresponding values. Both are equal in length and `values` are in decreasing order.

Here's my approach to the problem:

1. Convert the input to a `Map<Integer, List<String>> valuesToListMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());`. Why? Because that map will tell the substrings I would need to find permutations for (in your example it would be `{a},{b,c,d},{e,f},{g}` and since the map is of type `TreeMap` and the entries in it will be in reverse natural ordering (descending) order, I can ensure the entries in the map are in strictly decreasing order. Sample entry in my map given your input will be `18 -> {b,c,d}`
2. Next, I will iterate through the values of the `valuesToListMap`. I will find permutations of every list. For our example the output would be `{{a},{bcd,bdc,cbd,cdb,dbc,dcb},{ef,fe},{g}`. Lets call that collection `permutationsList`
3. Next, I will iterate over the `permutationsList` two entries at a time and start appending each element of first entry with each element of second entry . For example, I will append each element of entry `{a}` in `permutationsList` with each element of entry `{bcd,bdc,cbd,cdb,dbc,dcb}`. So my output after the merge will be `{abcd,abdc,acbd,acdb,adbc,adcb}`
4. Continue doing step 3 recursively and you should have your output

**Some notes:** 
Using `TreeMap` ensures we don't have an output `bcdaefg` because that is not in descending order of values.

My solution is below. I have not done any input validation or sanity checks but that should be easy to do:

```
public class PermutationWithinSubsection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> alphabets = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");
    List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(25,18,18,18,14,14,12);
    // Step 1 start
    Map<Integer, List<String>> valuesToListMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder()); // Order the map in reverse order of values
    for(int i=0; i<alphabets.size(); i++) {
        if(valuesToListMap.containsKey(values.get(i))) {
            List<String> temp = valuesToListMap.get(values.get(i));
            temp.add(alphabets.get(i));
            valuesToListMap.put(values.get(i),temp);
        } else {
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            temp.add(alphabets.get(i));
            valuesToListMap.put(values.get(i), temp);
        }
    }
    // Step 1 end

    // Step 2 start
    List<List<String>> permutationsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(List<String> ip: valuesToListMap.values()) {
       List<String> result = new PermutationWithinSubsection().permute(ip);
        permutationsList.add(result);
    }
    // Step 2 end

    // // Step 3 start
    int count = 1;
    List<String> l1 = permutationsList.get(0);
    List<String> r = new PermutationWithinSubsection().merge(l1, permutationsList, count);
    // // Step 3 end
    System.out.println("r = " + r);
}

/**
 * Find permutations of input list using backtracking
 * @param ip
 * @return
 */
private List<String> permute(List<String> ip) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    backtrack(list, new ArrayList<>(), ip);
    return list;
}

private void backtrack(List<String> list, ArrayList<String> tempList, List<String> nums) {
    if(tempList.size() == nums.size()){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s: tempList) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        list.add(sb.toString());
    } else{
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            if(tempList.contains(nums.get(i))) continue; // element already exists, skip
            tempList.add(nums.get(i));
            backtrack(list, tempList, nums);
            tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Keep on merging lists till we have merged all
 * @param l1
 * @param resultLists
 * @param count
 * @return
 */
private List<String> merge(List<String> l1, List<List<String>> resultLists, int count) {
    if(count == resultLists.size()) {
        return l1;
    }
    List<String> l2 = resultLists.get(count);
    List<String> f = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s1: l1) {
        for(String s2: l2) {
            f.add(s1+s2);
        }
    }
    return merge(f,resultLists,++count);
}
```

}

Output: `r = [abcdefg, abcdfeg, abdcefg, abdcfeg, acbdefg, acbdfeg, acdbefg, acdbfeg, adbcefg, adbcfeg, adcbefg, adcbfeg]`

Hope my explanation was clear. Let me know if you have any questions.